# In IndexedDB how can I return the value from an object for all the records in the DB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have several objects stored in my IndexedDB objectStore. These objects each have several keys, one of which is the name of the sports team. Example of my object:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the value of full_name for each of these objects. Can I do this by directly querying IndexedDB with the objectStore.getAll() method? My code currently looks like this:

```
async getData() {
  const db = await openDB('nbaPlayersTeams', 1);
  const tx = db.transaction('nbaPlayersTeamsStore', 'readonly');
  const store = tx.objectStore('nbaPlayersTeamsStore');
  const allTeams = await store.getAll();
  console.log(allTeams);
  db.close();
}
```

Thanks,
Bez

Comment: Yes you can use the getAll method and look at the full_name value of each object

Comment: Hi @Josh, so I use the getAll method to get all the objects in the objectStore and then iterate through them to get the full_name?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively I think you can try creating an index on full_name and opening a cursor over the index that just uses the cursor.key or something like that. I think that still incurs the full deserialization cost though.